# Who is a good host for a realtime TCP/IP game server?

Tags: c#, sockets, hosting

I a trying to set up a real time game server that runs a game I am writing as a C# .NET 3.5 service. The game is similar to classic pong so I need to send real time feedback to both clients through a persistent socket connect to the server.

This is an example of how it is coded.
http://www.codeproject.com/kb/IP/socketsByBobJanova.aspx

Does anyone know of any hosting services that can support this? I am only concerned with getting an reasonably priced host that I can test in for now.

Comment: Why vote to close? I cannot continue programming until I find a good host.

Comment: I agree people ask the same question for web hosting and those are usually not closed.

Comment: I think that is a perfectly valid question. Do different than what's a good tool that does X so I can do Y? Wish people could vote to take away people close power.

Comment: I would understand if I just wanted to host a "boxed" game server but I am writing one in C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here is a shot as an answer other then just a simple hosting company.  I am not sure of your means, but what I did was pay about $300 a month for a 1/4 rack colocation in Chicago, IL.  For that I get all the redundant power and bandwidth I need (29Mb up, 72Mb down normally).  I then went on EBay and got myself a couple Dell PowerEdge 2850 Dual 2.8GHz Xeon, 4GB RAM, 3x73GB 15k RPM RAID for about $350 each.  Put them all in, and *boom*, instant data-center.

I figure it took me about 15-20 hours to setup everything, $1000 in hardware, and $300 a month in colo fees.  So it is not for everyone, but for the small business that needs control of their servers, but need more performance/reliability then hosted, it is not a bad option.

Comment: Thanks! I am really shooting for 100$/month since the project is still in the testing phase. But 300$ is a good starting point I will use your solution if I do not find a cheaper one :>